# How Does The Magento 2 Product Discounts Work?

Tags: magento

Looking at the [Magento Quick Reference Documentation](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/quick-reference/) , in product -> extension_attributes -> discounts, the API offers an `array` of `objects` one can use for discounting products in Magento 2.

**Questions:**

1. Why is an array of objects needed?
2. Is there somewhere to view "discounts" by navigating from the Magento Dashboard?
3. Could each key/value pair field options be explained in plain English?

**JSON Example**

```
{
    "discounts": [
        {
            "discount_data": { "amount": 0.00, "base_amount": 0.00, "base_original_amount": 0.00, "original_amount": 0.00 },
            "rule_id": 0,
            "rule_label": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

**Key Value Pairs:**

1. discount_data ->
   a) amount
   b) base_amount
   c) base_original_amount
   d) original_amount
2. rule_id
3. rule_label

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do to create a custom REST API for the discounted product? Meanwhile, to answer your questions:

**Answers:**

1: Third-party developers cannot change the API Data interface in the Magento core. So, adding extension attributes is the only way to affect interfaces using configuration. The array is formed in the coding structure of the main object of the product, so please make sure to attach the additional details.

So, this custom data, i.e., your extension attribute, will be added as an array for the extensible product object.

2: Navigate to Marketing->cart price rules or catalog price rules applied to the product category.

[image]

Also, check the product as:

Navigate to **Products > Catalog**, select the required item and click 'Edit.'

You can scroll down and click on Advance Price to check if the special price and date are set.

[image]

**3: Key Value Pair**

Please specify for which API you want to create so we can explain the key value like order or product.

To order the object:

```
{
  "paymentMethod": {
    "method": "banktransfer"
  },
  "billing_address": {
    "email": "jdoe@example.com",
    "region": "New York",
    "region_id": 43,
    "region_code": "NY",
    "country_id": "US",
    "street": ["160 1st St."],
    "postcode": "11501",
    "city": "Mineola",
    "telephone": "516-555-1111",
    "firstname": "Jane",
    "lastname": "Doe"
  }
}
```

Full documentation: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/quick-reference/

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/tutorials/inventory/create-order.html